# Getting NullPointerException while transforming Dom element to string

Tags: java, xml

I am getting NullPointerException in the following code:

```
String str = SOME_HTML_STRING;
Node node = convertStrIntoNodeUsingJTidy();
domToString(node);

//converts node to string    
public static String domToString(org.w3c.dom.Node node)throws Exception {
    try {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

        // NullPointerException at this line, although node is not null
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw)); 
        return sw.toString();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error converting to String", ex);
    }
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
at com.example.Util.domToString(Util.java:3179)
... 128 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream.processingInstruction(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.processingInstruction(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
... 131 more
```

I have already checked the following link:
http://geekymeeky.blogspot.in/2008/10/javaxxmltransform-transformerexception.html

The above post says, if a text node is null then this exception occurs.

I want to know, what value of variable **str** caused the text node value to null and lead to this exception.

Comment: And what is `SOME_HTML_STRING`?

Comment: Are you sure `node` is not null? Try to add `assert node != null` before transforming.

Comment: @fge That is what I want to know. Actually one of our customer has reported this error. I tried every possible scenario of `SOME_HTML_STRING`, but I am not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: @user1516873 I tried passing the `node` value to `null`, but even that is not causing the `NullPointerException`. That's why I am pretty sure that `node` value is not null.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you can see in stack trace, Exception was throws when parser trying to parse some incorrect [processing instruction](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1004215813).

You can easily reproduce it with code below:

```
    Document d = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
    Node n = d.createProcessingInstruction("test", null);
    System.out.println(domToString(n));
```

what raises exception almost like your.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:732)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:336)
    at TestNode.domToString(TestNode.java:63)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream.processingInstruction(ToXMLStream.java:281)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.processingInstruction(ToUnknownStream.java:886)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.DOM2TO.parse(DOM2TO.java:90)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:679)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:723)
    ... 33 more
```

**EDIT:**

Similar exception happen when you get empty comments or textNodes, for example:

```
    Node n = d.createComment("test");
    n.setTextContent(null); // throws exception on parse


    Node n = d.createTextNode(null); // throws exception on parse
```

It is not common situation, and possible only if incorrect/corrupted xml was passes as input source.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. One more thing, I want to ask from you that whether this is the only condition for the occurrence of this exception. I just want to make sure that after fixing this, I will not get this exception again in another scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much for showing the solution to my bug. Setting a text value to `null` to should throw an exception if it is not allowed!